# Create a web part which takes input from a tasklist

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm in need of creation of a web part which takes input from a task list and changes the color of the tasklist based on the data in the task list. Can anyone help me with this problem?
I can write code in visual studio 2005.
My question is how do I take input data from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code here. This should get you started. ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/e3225ad4-75e6-4d78-b0ee-1b8e566778fc/))

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;  

class SPTest {  
 public void ReadList() {  
  // Use using to make sure resources are released properly  
  using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(pathToSite)) {  
    using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.AllWebs[nameOfWeb]) {   
      // Alternately you can use oSite.RootWeb if you want to access the main site  

      SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[listName];  // The display name, ie. "Calendar"  

      foreach(SPListItem oItem in oList.Items) {  
        // Access each item in the list...  
        DateTime startTime = (DateTime)oItem["Start Time"];  
        // etc....  
      }  

    }  
  }  

 }  
}
```